# Extracting information from console only if there is change in output

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

Here is what I am trying to accomplish:

App runs in cron and checks available prices,

```
./checkprice | grep price
```

it then returns:

```
run at October 15
price item1 19.99
price item2 2.99
price item3 3.99

run at October 16
price item1 19.49
price item2 2.99
price item3 3.99
```

The reason why you see two entries for item 2 is that because price change

How do I input new prices into a file that has the following format:

```
item1
19.99

item2
2.99

item3
3.99
```

Comment: i don't know how `./checkprice | grep price` prints the above result..

Comment: "How do I input ...?" With an editor? It's not really clear what you're asking... Taking a wild guess, maybe you want something like  `./checkprice | awk '$1 == "price" { printf "%s\n%s\n\n",$2,$3 }' >> my_price_file.txt`...

Answer (score 0):

sed is a Single line EDitor, so you will have to use awk or change your file format.  I would personally change the file format and do something like this.

```
item1 19.99
item2 4.99
```

then when you get new prices you can do something like this.

```
cmd="sed -i 's/$item.*/$item $price/' file"
eval $cmd
```